# How to Select data range in excel which are between more than one space

Tags: excel, select, vba

```
1
23
18

11
3

210
```

I need to Select all the data from 1 to 210 using a vba code. Also no of rows will be changed accordingly.

Comment: Some spaces will be there between data.

Answer (score 0):

If 210 is the last value in column A,

```
RowFinal = Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row
```

will give you its row.

```
Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(RowFinal, "A")).Select
```

will select the column.